# Order of various functions

Tags: asymptotics

I am to arrange the following 30 functions in terms of increasing order

**( all the lg (log) are to the base 2.
log* represents iterated logarithm.)**

[image]

Here's my answer (*the functions on the same level are of the same order)*:

1 ,  [image] 

lglg*n

```
lg*n,      lg*(lgn)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image] , [image]

[image] , [image]

[image] , [image]

[image]

[image], [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am not sure where to insert (logn)!. I know (logn)! = o((logn)^logn) and logn = o((logn)!), *isn't it*. But where exactly would it fit. Can anyone help me with that. Also I would really appreciate if someone could verify that my arrangement is right or not.

Thank you.

EDIT : I MEANT TO ASK THE POINT OF INSERTION OF (LOGN)! IN THE ABOVE LIST SORTED IN TERMS OF INCREASING ORDER. Simple.

Comment: We don't check homework here. This is your TA's job.

Comment: Use Stirling approximation.

Comment: Could you use LaTeX instead of pictures? It may happen that you do not know order of some element - it is a good potential question about that particular element, but I bet that you have no problem with $n, n^2, n^3, 2^n$. I mean that the whole excersise is not proper question, but also you do not need feedback to all of them. Trimming down the question would point to the source of the confusion.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus It ain't no homework.

Comment: @Emil tried that, can't close in on the exact locaton.

Comment: @Evil, roger that mate, I just listed it all out just hoping that if there's some mistake in the entire arrangement then someone might point it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting functions by asymptotic growth](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth)

Answer (score 2):

Stirling's formula asserts that
$$
n! = \Theta(\sqrt{n}(n/e)^n).
$$
Thus
$$
(\log n)! = \Theta(\sqrt{\log n}((\log n)/e)^{\log n}).
$$

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question. The set needs a complete ordering. Where in the list would should that function be placed. I was able to use Stirling's formula to deduce (logn)! = o((logn)^logn).